# Why does lhs of this integral seem to diverge while the rhs does not?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int_{0}^\infty \exp(x(c-1))dx = \int_{0}^\infty \exp(-x(-c+1))dx \\ \frac{\exp(x(c-1))}{c-1} \Big|_0^\infty=\frac{\exp(-x(c+1))}{c-1} \Big|_0^\infty \\
$$

Comment: Because the term on the bottom right is wrong?

Comment: Both converge iff $c<1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top row is correct, you have something of the form $e^{-ax}$ where you need $a>0$ for convergence. The bottom row is however wrong